# How to run manage.py inside venv?

Tags: python, django, bash, python-venv

I have been given an existing project to work on and I am really struggling to get the environment set up.

The project folder firstly contains manage.py server, which I use as an entry point to run the server.

There is also a venv folder which contains all the modules etc. I need.

So when I do runserver on manage.py, I get that "*No module named sqlserver_ado.base*". Even when I have activated the virtual environment and am in  bash.... this module for instance is in venv folder in a `venv\Lib\site-packages`.

I am so very confused. I have also tried copying whatever modules are said to be missing and have ran into other issues this way also.

Comment: This should help (it's mine): http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate but you haven't posted enough information to make sure I selected the right duplicate.  There is a large number of questions with this error message; the *good* ones contain specific details about which OS and Python version the OP is on, and a copy of *exactly* and *only* the problematic code (see also the [mcve] guidance in [help]).  If you need detailed help still, please update your question with these details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. run `virtualenv venv` in you desired directory
2. after install from t run :
   `source \your_folder\venv\bin\activate`
3. now you sohuld see  `(venv)` before $ in the shell
   that mean you env is active
4. install packages run `pip install package_name`
5. run `pip freeze` to get installed packages
6. go to project folder that include `manage.py` file
7. run `python manage.py runserver` to make sure that evrything run fine

to access django-shell run `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 0):

Download the module you wish to install, unzip.
Get the path of your virtualenv's python binary. On windows for me it is `/Documents/web/env_mysite/Scripts/python.exe.`

No go to the dir where you have unzipped the module and do the following.

```
/Documents/web/env_mysite/Scripts/python.exe setup.py install
```